# change element name with attribute value using XSLT

Tags: xslt, attributes, element

I want to change element name with attribute value

My input xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
   <ROW id="1">
      <D n="ord_code">10033</D>
      <D n="po_commts">Part and Service Requisition Example</D>
      <D n="createddt">2021-02-11 00:00:00.0</createddt>
   </ROW>
   <ROW id="2">
      <D n="ord_code">10018</D>
      <D n="po_commts">GL Test</D>
      <D n="createddt">2021-02-04 00:00:00.0</D>
   </ROW>
</Envelope>
```

my expected result child element name replaced with attribute value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
   <ROW id="1">
      <ord_code>10033</ord_code>
      <po_commts>Part and Service Requisition Example</po_commts>
      <createddt>2021-02-11 00:00:00.0</createddt>
   </ROW>
   <ROW id="2">
      <ord_code>10018</ord_code>
      <po_commts>GL Test</po_commts>
      <createddt>2021-02-04 00:00:00.0</createddt>
   </ROW>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I am trying with below code but getting syntax error  ``` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="D">
      <xsl:element name="{@n}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet> ```

Comment: You weren't too far from getting it. When you ask a question post the code you have tried so far in your question.

Comment: Thank you Very much Sebastien. I will follow from next time. Actually there were more fields in my xml . one of the field attribute is number. so I was getting an error because of that. I just noticed. Thank you once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="D">
    <xsl:element name="{@n}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcy2